# video.js - Defaults to Flash player

Tags: video.js

Works in Google but in the latest version of FF it defaults to Flash. Also won't play on andriod at all. Video files are mp4

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firefox can't play MP4, so Flash fallback has to be used. Include a webm or ogv source if you want to avoid Flash on Firefox.

MP4 on Android should be fine. Can you give some code/a link?